# Sherlock Action Bar: Apply style for 3.0 and 2.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I am trying to add my style for an action bar that I have in my code. I want them to look identical over all platforms. The issue right now is that my buttons, alertdialogs, and action bar (to name a few) are not the same from 2.3 to 4.1.

I want the everything to have the same theme as the `Holo.Light` theme and I want to apply the action bar style to both 2.3 and 3.0.

Here is my code for action bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light"> 
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="background">@color/YakOrange</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/YakOrange</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:height">15dip</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The issue with this is since I have my minSDK at 10 the `<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>` is an error. Without this I can't get anything above 3.0 to have that style.

If someone can help me with this theme stuff that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need put a target version in your manifest file:
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
when you put only a minSdkVersion sometimes the project acquires that like tareget version, when you compiler utilize.

Comment: @MariaMercedesWyssAlvarez I have a target set for version 11. Still no success.